# Effect of inert gas blanket on oxygen solubilized in wine

Tags: thermodynamics, solubility, gas-laws

If applied to a volume of wine, could a blanket of argon become dense enough to remove oxygen from the wine? This is not a question of sparging the wine. Rather, could a blanket of argon over the top of a wine remove dissolved oxygen from the volume? No external pressure is applied, temperature is 55 degrees F.

Comment: Partially, it can, as there is direct proportionality at equilibrium between oxygen concentration in wine and oxygen volume percentage in the gas above. But it will take time until the equilibrium is established, unless forced mechanically.

Comment: At ambient conditions, the density of argon is greater than the of air; thus argon may displace air (one reason it is used as a protecting gas in chemistry and welding).  But in a barrel, it will just sit *on top* of the surface of the liquid.  Solvents for chromatography (a purification method) are sometimes degassed by placing the 2L bottles in an ultrasound bath to remove gasses dissolved in these liquids.  (There equally are ultrasound heads to immerse into containers, too.) I do not know if / how much such a treatment with ultrasound would harm (especially the taste of) wine.

Answer (score 2):

A layer of added argon at atmospheric pressure would be inert and would not significantly alter the solubility of oxygen in the wine. Any effect would *not* be due to direct interaction between the gases (so certainly not chemical).

If the headspace of a wine bottle is flushed with argon (displacing the air above the wine), the oxygen in the wine will re-equilibrate into the headspace volume, resulting in a decrease in the amount of oxygen solubilized in the wine. The effect can be significant, but surprisingly small. For instance, for a 750 mL wine bottle with a 5 mL headspace (ullage), the ratio of oxygen in the headspace and liquid is ~1:5:

$$\frac{n_\ce{O2(l)}}{n_\ce{O2(g)}}=\frac{RT}{K_\textrm{c}}\frac{V_\textrm{l}}{V_\textrm{g}} = 0.032 \frac{V_\textrm{l}}{V_\textrm{g}}$$

This means that flushing the headspace will reduce the total oxygen in the bottle by only ~17%.

Note also: the density of argon will depend on the pressure. Since the argon is not pressurized above atmospheric pressure, the maximum pressure of argon will be approximately atmospheric pressure when all of the air is flushed out of the headspace, and lower otherwise. The density of argon in the headspace will be proportional to the pressure and will be a maximum if all of the air is flushed away. The remaining volume of the headspace will be occupied by air (including of course oxygen).